# PHP CLI script with SSH2 terminates without message

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, scp

I have a long running PHP script that is synching two systems and using SSH2 to upload files to a Server. The script is executed using a cronjob.

My problem is, that the script just terminates (sometimes after 1 hour, sometimes after two hours) without any output. I couldn't find anything in PHP's error logs, nor in the systemlogs. This happens equally on three separate machines.

Basically this is my code (please imaging error handling etc. included) for the upload:

```
$oFtpStream = fopen('ssh2.sftp://' . $this->sUser . ':' . $this->sPassword . '@' .$this->sHost . ':' . $this->iPort . $psTargetFile, 'w');

$sFileContents = file_get_contents($psSourceFile);

fwrite($oFtpStream, $sFileContents) === false) 
fclose($oFtpStream);
ssh2_sftp_chmod($this->oFtpConn, $psTargetFile, 0777);
```

I would be really thankfull for any thoughts/ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if all you are doing is sync'ing files, use this https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: I'm with @Dimi, no need to use PHP here at all. Lots of directly-callable tools can be dropped right into cron: rsync, ncftpget, scp, curl, wget...

Comment: Are you sure PHP execution time limit is not stepping in? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - if this is executed in a cronjob then most probably not as the PHP CLI is not time limited. Also hitting the time limit would create an entry in the error log.

Comment: The process is retrieving and processing data from an API as well and downloading the files from the API system, so unfortunately we can’t just do an rsync.